# Scheduling four exams in a $31$-day period

Tags: combinatorics

This is a continuation of [Schedule four different exams in a $31$-day period with restriction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957239/schedule-four-different-exams-in-a-31-day-period-with-restriction/2957266#2957266).

If someone can check my attempts below:

> A professor has to schedule four different exams in a $31$-day period. No more than one exam can be scheduled in any one day.

**(a) In how many ways can he schedule the exams?**

Step $1$: Choose the day for exam $1$: $31$ choices

Step $2$: Choose the day for exam $2$: $30$ choices

Step $3$&$4$: Analogous to previous: $29\cdot 28$ choices.

So there are $31\cdot 30 \cdot 29\cdot 28$ ways to schedule the exams.

However, there are $4!$ ways to arrange the exams themselves. So there are $4!\times (31\cdot 30 \cdot 29\cdot 28)$ ways to arrange the exams.

**(b) In how many ways can he schedule the exams if there should be at least three days off between any two finals?**

Consider the complement where there are either $0,1$ or $2$ days between any two finals.

Case $1$: $0$ days between any two finals

This would mean the tests are on consecutive days. Consider $E_1 E_2 E_3 E_4$ as one unit. There are $8$ choices to place the exams.

(I drew $31$ spaces for the exams and put slashes after every $4$ spaces.)

Case $2$: $1$ days between any two finals

There are $5$ choices to place the exams.

(Using the $31$ spaces for the exams, I put slashes after every $6$ spaces)

Case $3$: $2$ days between any two finals

Using same approach in previous cases, there are $3$ choices of placing the exams.

Considering there are $4!$ ways to arrange the exams themselves. There are $4!\times (8+5+3)=384$ ways to schedule the exams. (BAD CASES)

> So, there are $4!\times (31\cdot 30\cdot 29\cdot 28) - 384$ way to
>   schedule the exams such that there are at least three days between any
>   two finals.

Note: I am not sure this attempt is correct. This is how I understood it.

Comment: there are more cases for part b) that you should also consider. For example, two exams are on the same day but the other two can be on any other day.

Comment: the restriction in the statement of the problem says that no more than $1$ exam can be schedule in any one day @Vasya

Comment: The $4!$ is errant. You implicitly ordered the exams when you took the product $31\cdot 30\cdot 29\cdot 28$. Just rename the exams "math", "science", etc, and you see that when you say there are $31$ choices for when the math exam and so on, that imposes an order on the exams.

Comment: so just remove the $4!$ and the attempt is fine?

Comment: What Vasya is saying is that I could put exam 1 on day 1, exam 2 on day 2, exam 3 on day 10, and exam 4 on day 20. This is a bad case, but you never count it among your bad cases. (re $4!$: the first part, without the $4!$, is correct, but the second is not.)

Comment: oh okay...so how do i go about part (b)

Comment: @KevinLong i was trying to use the complement for part (b)

Comment: @rover2: for part b) I would start like this: the latest we can schedule the first exam is 19th (3 days between the exams). There are $4!$ ways to arrange exams. Next, move the starting exam to 18th and you have an equivalent of the stars and bars problem. How many ways to put that extra day into one of the four intervals/bins?

Comment: For part a) isn't the answer simply 31 choose 4?

Comment: @KevinLong see comment above

Comment: @rover2 Christian Blatter has a correct answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (b): There are $4$ black days $\bullet$, then $9$ compulsory white days $\circ$, and $18$ optional white days $\circ$. The black days and the optional white days can be arranged in ${18+4\choose 4}$ ways. For each such arrangement insert three compulsory white days immediately after each of the three first black days in order to obtain an admissible sequence. Finally attribute a particular exam to each of the black days. It follows that there are
$${22\choose4}\cdot 4!=175\,560$$
admissible schedules.